# How to load an image in kingfisher without an image view?

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

Kingfisher allows for some easy methods to load images asynchronously from network or cache, for instance:

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)
```

Is there a way to load the image directly outside of the context of the image view?  I.e. something like this:

```
Kingfisher.loadImage(with: imageUrl) { image in ... }
```

Comment: What’s the use case?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you just use

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage
```

That function should have everything you need